# Return collection from await

Tags: java, awaitility

I'm using Awaitility tool and I need to return a collection from await to be able to work with it later.

I have a collection returned from a GET call:

```
Collection collection = usersService.getAllUsers();
```

The following code works (GET call is executed up to 5 times in order to meet the conditions):

```
    waitForEvent(() -> usersService.getAllUsers()).size());
```

Where:

```
private void waitForEvent(Callable<Integer> collectionSize) {
    await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(collectionSize, greaterThan(5));
}
```

But I need to pass a Collection (not its size) to be able to reuse it. Why this code is not working (GET call is executed just once and it waits for 5 sec)?

```
waitForEvent2(usersService.getAllUsers());
```

Where

```
private Collection waitForEvent2(Collection collection) {
    await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(collectionSize(collection), greaterThan(5));
    return collection;
}

private Callable<Integer> collectionSize(Collection collection) {
    return new Callable<Integer>() {
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return collection.size(); // The condition supplier part
        }
    };
}
```

What do I need to do so that GET request was polled several times with collection passed as a parameter?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to return the `Collection`? Sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me

Comment: I dont see why first snippet would work and second one would not.  The problem is that first snippet does not include what `collectionSize` actually is. Is it the same callable ?

Comment: Added usage examples.
@Lino I used Collection in order to reuse it with both Lists and Maps

Comment: @Nataliya what stops you from declaring a `Collection` variable and store the result of `userService.getAllUsers()` inside that?

Comment: @Lino I guess this is the main problem, as the collection is assigned to variable, so polling is not working (GET request is executed just once). Seems like polling works on `size()` method, not on `usersService.getAllUsers().size()`. In other words, `usersService.getAllUsers()` is not executed in retry

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously in first snippet you are using

```
usersService.getAllUsers().size()
```

and that gets called multiple times (calling service -> get call)

and in second you are using only

```
collection.size()
```

and that won't fetch anything - because why would it - but still will be called the same amount of time.

What you could do (which I dont like) is

```
private Callable<Integer> collectionSize(Collection collection) {

    return new Callable<Integer>() {
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            collection.clear();
            collection.addAll(usersService.getAllUsers());
            return collection.size(); // The condition supplier part
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this snippet works. But is there any possibility not to hardcode `usersService.getAllUsers()`, so that I was able to reuse this method? 
Also, this does not solve the main problem: GET request is performed twice

Comment: Maybe it gets correct size after 2 calls. You can pass service call as a producer as well.

Comment: what exectly do you mean regarding passing service call as a producer?

Answer (score 0):

it is general approach I use to return any value from awaitility await

```
private List <User> getUsers() {
    AtomicReference<List<User>> ref = new AtomicReference<>();
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS)
            .pollDelay(30, MILLISECONDS)
            .until(() -> {
                        ref.set(usersService.getAllUsers());
                        return !ref.get().isEmpty(); //another condition
                    }
            );
    return ref.get();
}
```